# Remove autocomplete option in text field

Tags: forms, firefox, autocomplete, textfield

I mistakenly wrote a wrong value into a text field and now everytime I start typing Firefox suggests me such value for autocompletion. I would like Firefox to never suggest it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single autocomplete options can be removed by:

- entering into the textfield that shows such option to be removed
- activate the suggestions by pressing down arrow key
- highlight the option to be removed (using the arrow keys or hovering, but not clicking, the mouse over such option)
- pressing the del key